# How does Lucene handle duplicate documents?

Tags: indexing, lucene, benchmarking

I am using Lucene 8.3 and want to understand in detail how Lucene handles duplicate documents? Does it have intelligence to detect duplicate doc and skip it from indexing? Your help will be much appreciated.
For reference, I am using English Wikipedia dump for indexing.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Have you researched this question yourself? There are some questions and answers on Stack Overflow which already discuss the topic of Lucene duplicate documents. You could also run some simple tests, to see how Lucene handles repeatedly adding the same document to an index. That may help you to ask a more focused question, for a specific issue.